# magento error creating a block

Tags: magento

I created a new module, in which I am creating a block by the following method in `IndexController.php` which is at `app/code/local/Ashfame/Helloblock/controllers/IndexController.php`

```
class Ashfame_Helloblock_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        // this works fine
        $block = new Ashfame_Helloblock_Block_Helloblock();
        echo $block->toHtml();
    }

    public function layoutAction() {
        // this doesn't work
        $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
        $block = $layout->createBlock('ashfame_helloblock/helloblock','root');
        var_dump( $block ); // this returns false
        echo $block->toHtml();
    }
}
```

My Block class is `Ashfame_Helloblock_Block_Helloblock` and is at `app/code/local/Ashfame/Helloblock/Block/Helloblock.php`

Since the `$block` in `layoutAction()` is false, PHP throws an error `Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object`

On debugging I found that the magento is figuring out the class name wrong. It figure out the class name as `mage_Ashfame_helloblock_block` inside `getGroupedClassName()`.

What's wrong here?

Comment: What does your app/code/local/Ashfame/Helloblock/etc/config.xml look like?

Comment: Good job tracing through the classname mapping. An explorer's heart is so important in Magento development.

Comment: @benmarks heh thanks! I second that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your configuration file. In `app/code/local/Ashfame/Helloblock/etc/config.xml` you should have:

```
<config>
  ...
  <global>
    ...
    <blocks>
        <ashfame_helloblock>
             <class>Ashfame_Helloblock_Block</class>
        </ashfame_helloblock>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it, just that `<ashfame_helloblock>` needs to be `<Ashfame_Helloblock>` for it to work :)

Comment: I take that comment back. Must have been something else at that time. This needs to be in lowercase as shown in the sample code block.